# How to use temporary tables with parallelism in a transaction?

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, parallel-processing, transactions

I have a method that can be described with the following steps:

1. Insert rows into temporary table 1.
2. Insert rows into temporary table 2.
3. Insert (inner join of table 1 + table 2) into temporary table 3.
4. Select rows of temporary table 3.

The steps are executed sequentially. However, it is a slow method, and I want to parallelize STEP1 and STEP 2, because they are independent. It is important to know that the 3 temporary tables have the clause "ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS" so all the steps must be performed in a single transaction.

```java
private void temporaryTables() {

    String st1 = "insert into table1(name) values('joe')";
    String st2 = "insert into table2(name) values('foo')";

    jdbcTemplate.update(st1);
    jdbcTemplate.update(st2);

    //Arrays.asList(st1,st2).parallelStream().map(x -> {
    //    jdbcTemplate.update(x);
    //});
    //if I use parallel stream and I select both tables, one table is empty.

}

@Transactional
public List<Response> method() {
    temporaryTables();
    return jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_TABLE_3, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Response.class));
}
```

If I uncomment the parallel code, it doesn't work as expected. It only works with the caller thread, the other thread won't execute in the same transaction, and because of that STEP 3 will fail because one temporary table is empty.

I also tried with raw JDBC transactions. However, I can't share the Connection object because it is synchronized.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well, two paralel threads needs two separate database sessions - you cannot deffer commit in one session, because the other session will not see any changes from the first session. On the other hands you cannot commit because rows will be deleted on commit. Hopeless situation, it cannot be done in this design.

Comment: You could try define a view with both tables (table1 and table2), then insert into view. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#i1006232